# What arguments do scholars present for historicity of the fall?

Tags: fall-of-man

What arguments and writings have been used to defend the Genesis account of the fall as a historical event? Is there evidence apart from the writings in Genesis that man was at one time *not* fallen?

Comment: Appreciate. Can I have reason for opening this question? I mean how this formulation was better than first one: What evidence there is that fall of men is actual fact? I mean I see that current formulation is more specific and focused I think so and answer can now be more even shorter than giving broad list of evidences for the first formulation.

Comment: In the first version, you asked if there were documents to defend the historical fall. The answer  is "Yes. Scripture." In this regard, EVERY Christian tradition has some definition of the fall, so all would answer "yes" and feel like they were affirming a tautology. Secondly, you asked if it can be proven if the fall is factual, to which others said "we're evil, so it's obvious" and your question allowed them to take such a stance. What you want to do is rule out the possibility of bad answers by asking a great question. The specificity allows for more clarity in what it is you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming, you're looking for evidence of a transition from unfallen-ness to fallen-ness, not merely evidence of fallen-ness.

If a satisfactory answer to your question requires, in a Young Earth view, something like an archeological artifact (say, a book  that Adam wrote in the few hours/days before he Fell), I think you'll be lacking.

In a philosophical sense, C.S. Lewis in *Mere Christianity* tried to make a "logical" case for the necessity of evil being a corrupted good, rather than an eternally evil bad. But again, this may be more of a view of the "fall" of the devil moreso than mankind.

If one holds to a literalist-old-earth Creation view, there could be some evidence in extinction rates. Reasons to Believe, an old-earth think tank, says:

> Roughly half the bird species alive on Earth when humans appeared no longer exist, and more than a tenth of those that remain face imminent extinction. While evolutionary theory offers no explanation for this change from proliferation of bird species to diminution, the Bible does ....

http://www.reasons.org/articles/extinction-risks-for-birds

Comment: Extra questions: Have you read Mere Christianity? What do you think about it? Does it explain the beginning of creation, man and the Fall?

Comment: @ptrandon: Hello. I'd like you to answer following question: Do you think that evidence in extinction rate is only one argument for the historicity of the fall?